# Text size doesn't keep aspect ratio in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, button, text

[phone image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdPdO.png)
[tablet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSLS5.png)
I am using this line of code in android studio

```
btn_play_game1.setTextSize(16 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density );
```

to set the text size to a button (that has an image on it). The text is "Clear The Way" but on phone emulator looks very big and smaller on tablet.
Why the text is not as adapt to the screen size and keep the aspect ratio?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of multiplying your font with display density you should use the resource declared in `dimens.xml` file like `getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size_medium)` this way it would not only take care of the device density but also take into account the font size set by the device user.